# Need to convert SQL Query to Coredata Format

Tags: sql, swift, core-data, nspredicate

SQL Query

```
select * from zchildren where zparent = 3586 OR zparent in (Select zid from zchildren where zparent = 3586)
```

I have tried few cases with `$SUBQUERY` but Still i am not getting any success. So how can i achieve this ?

**Update**

I have Table Name which is **Children** which has **Parent** which contains the ID of the same table ID , Its a **Inverse Relationship** now i want All the children which parent is **'3586'** and its all sub children

## Update2

I am Attaching the screen shot

### [image]

**Now Few more points**

1. Table Group has One-To-Many Relationship with Children
2. Table Children has Two Relationship
3. First which is Inverse to Group One-To-One
4. Second children relation which is Inverse to itself which is called Reflexive

## Updated Question

Now suppose i have one Query i want to search from **Children** table where title is **'Medical'** AND Parent is **'3586'**
Now This **'3586'** is parent id which is coming from Table **Group** And i can easily predicate this .

#### Problem

It Gives me children whose parent **'3586'** but i also want to search in the title of sub-children which are Reflexive of this parent ID , Means sub-children of children which came from parent **'3586'**.

I really need this solution. I can still update my question if any one is not clear in this question.

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong end. How are your entities defined, what are the relationships between them and what are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @MartinR i have updated my answer

Comment: Please show your managed object subclass definitions.

Comment: @MartinR i have updated my question with screen shot also provided more information. is it Good enough ?

Answer (score 2):

When tackling somewhat complicated Core Data issues, you really have to be a bit more accurate. Your code and your variable names are sloppy and wrought with mistakes.

In your SQL query you have an attribute `parent` (or "zparent"), but in the Core Data model it becomes an attribute rather than a relationship. (Were you perhaps thinking of modeling ids? That would indicate that you are still trapped in relational database thinking and have not fully grasped the concept of the object graph yet. Forget about ids and think in relationships instead.)

You need a reverse relationship to `children`, so this cannot be the same relationship. Calling the entity "Children" is confusing because 1) you are using the plural for a singular object and 2) you are calling both parent and children "Children". You also misspell "Children" as "Childran", potentially leading to all sorts of errors.

Instead, let me suggest the entity name `Person`. A person can have one or more `parents` (or is it only one?) and one or more `children` both of which are also of type `Person`, resulting in a many-to-many relationship:

```
Person - parents <<----------------->> children - Person
```

If a person can only have one parent it if of course a many-to-one relationship.

```
Person - parent <------------------->> children - Person
```

You can then fetch a `Person` with `idNumber` 3586 (notice that using `id` is perhaps also a bad idea as it is a reserved word in some contexts). You can then access that person's children very succinctly:

```
person.children
```

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: First of all thanks mate for taking a time to notice my issue.  Second regarding field name Id is coming from json so i am using this for testing purpose in my other example nowi know i can get person.children from 3586 thats true but i also want to search in the sub children . so lets say if my parent id 3586 i can gets its children but i want to search in the subchildren.. so how can i do that ?

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: yes i know with recursive loops i can achieve this but with NSPredicate is it possible ?

Comment: If you was to model you data properly as @Mundi suggests then you could just make your predicate something like: `@"parent.uid == %@ || parent.parent.uid == %@", @3586, @3586` - obviously the length/complexity of this predicate depends how many levels of children you want to search

Comment: @Paul.s i dont know how much length, it will be its recursive and its upto n number of sub children.

Comment: @Mundi i have already set the one-to-many case but i am still confuse how to solve this case with NSPrdicate. Do you mean i have to remove inverse ?

Comment: Don't use a `NSPredicate`. Use the loop.

Comment: @Mundi ok so that will be the only option ?

Comment: You could change the data model to include an extra reference to *all* children for convenience.

Comment: @Mundi you mean i add the Extra ID of the Main parent to all Children , is it something you are referring ?

Comment: No, another to-many relationship called, say, `descendants` with references of all `Person`s down the line including the level. You would need a new entity for this purpose. And you need to modify potentially lots of records when you create or delete a person (can be automated in the `NSManagedObject` subclass).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85036/discussion-between-hardik-shah-and-mundi).